# making clusters dynamically so that if few data points are removed other clusters remain unaffected

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, k-means

I have a set of SIFT keypoints from a grey scale image. Is there a way that I can create clusters that do not get affected if distant keypoints are absent?

In k-means we have to decide that how many clusters we want. I am looking for method that decides K dynamically. Suppose I have `n` keypoints (where `n` is approximately  1000). Suppose the method makes 50 clusters.

Now, few keypoints are removed from one region then the method should give me same or similar clusters for areas from which keypoint was not removed.

It would be helpful if centroid of cluster undergoes very less deviation.

I tried to understand this [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330803841_A_dynamic_K-means_clustering_for_data_mining). [Another link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330803841_A_dynamic_K-means_clustering_for_data_mining/fulltext/5c54fddea6fdccd6b5db8b1f/330803841_A_dynamic_K-means_clustering_for_data_mining.pdf?origin=publication_detail).

But in it, the proposed method calculates threshold and does not use it.

Comment: So you want to re-run k-Means after removing some points and would like to have the same clusters (than in the original run) in regions where no points were removed?

Comment: May I ask why you want to recluster instead of using the result of the initial run?

Comment: i am looking for a way to use relative arrangement of clusters for identification.
I read somewhere long time back a way of detecting  connected component . it involved treating each point as alone and as you go along group closest points to form cluster . Finally distinct clusters will remain .Don't remember exact details.Maybe, that could work for my case .

Comment: I am still not sure where you are heading but you might want to look at [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) and [Single Link Clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-linkage_clustering)

Comment: ok . i will look into that .